# Group Think Challenge 2

Tags: word, letters

The list below are sets of related words which some of them has a letter clue.

What are these groups of four?

1. ---g-   ----  ----  ---r--
2. --r--  -----  ----  -e--
3. -o---  ------  ---  -l----
4. -u---- ------ ------  -a--
5. -----p-- ---  ------ ---t----
6. ----t   -------  ----  ----e
7. ----h-  ------   ----  --d--
8. -i--      -----      ---       w----
9. -----n---- ----o-- --------- ---------
10. --k-   -------   ----    --r-
11. -e-----  ---  --------   --------d--
12. --r      ------   -----   --s-------
13. s-----  ----------------  ----  -------

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.

> Ringo  Paul  John  George

2.

> North  South  East  West

3.

> Solid  Liquid  Gas  Plasma

4.

> Summer  Spring  Winter  Fall

5.

> Multiply Add Divide Subtract(SteveV)

6.

> Heart  Diamond  Club  Spade

7.

> Length  Height  Time  Width

8.

> Fire  Earth  Air  Water

9.

> Washington  Lincoln  Roosevelt  Jefferson(Mt. Rushmore)

10.

> Luke  Matthew  John  Mark

11.

> Lesbian  Gay  Bisexual  Transgender

12.

> War Famine Death Pestilence(SteveV)

13.

> Strong  Electromagnetism  Weak  Gravity

Comment: i believe 12 is rot13(Jne, Snzvar, Qrngu, Crfgvyrapr)

Comment: Sure!  And I think 5 is rot13(Zhygvcyl, Nqq, Qvivqr, Fhogenpg)

Comment: hint : einstien, park, people, nature

Comment: could #7 be ROT13(urvtug, yratgu, nern, jvqgu) ?

Comment: gvzr not nern.. 4th dimension

Comment: hint :  q for questioning or queer

Comment: 11 is Rot(Yrfovna, Tnl, Ovfrkhny, Genaftraqre)

Comment: Oh thanks I'll add that one @TwoBitOperation

Comment: no longer a partial answer!